# How to make responsive columns

Tags: android, material-design

I'm trying to make a dashboard like app to display real time data to a user in a vehicle with a layout similar to the included screenshot. I've tried googling for a direction to follow to try and mimic google's responsive grid columns design principle. However, I can't find any examples of that principle in practice on android. How would I go about implementing this type of design in android? Would you use Grid Layouts?

Ideally I'd like to be able to have a Grid Layout that has cells that are consistent in size that allow me to span a Card View across columns and rows but I don't know of a way to do this using a Grid layout. Any ideas?

Screenshot: https://gyazo.com/912c3414d9e8d46a1fa4eade54d620e6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html). It will allow you to define a grid and to span columns/rows. I was also going to mention [GridView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html), but I don't think that it allows spanning of cells.

Another possibility is [FleboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) if you need more flexibility. [TableLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) also permits spanning.

You can also build a grid layout directly with [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) using the "GuideLine" object.

Those are four layouts that I would consider.

Comment: Awesome thank you. Is there a way to create it with the layout locked to the size of the screen. so I can make all the cards placed within the layout but not passing the edges of the screen? Kind of locking them inside and not being able to scroll?

Comment: @JoelB I don't think any of the layouts I mention (other than GridView which is probably not appropriate for your application) can scroll on their own, so scrolling shouldn't be a problem. Other than that, just make sure that you widget sizes fit the screen dimensions so they don't disappear off to the side or top/bottom. If that is a concern for you, then FlexboxLayout may be the best choice since it can have widgets flow to the next line rather they disappear off to the side. I also added `ConstraintLayout` as another option to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm going to look into each option and try some things out.